# ComposeView in Fragment doesn't recreate after navigate out and back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

I started integrating ComposeView inside my Fragment A. It has the ability to navigate to Nav Graph B because of business logic.

After navigating to Nav graph B and back, ComposeView does not regenerate the view, the other part, which is XML-based, works well.

I'm also trying to add `setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)` to ComposeView, but nothing is affected.

My current workaround is adding `composeView.disposeComposition()` in `Fragment#onResume()`, but it looks not able to be cleared when I leave fragment A. (Proof is, the first time I enter fragment A, it cause a bit slow but after going back and forth, the view loads very quick).

Finally, here is my code. Please help. Thanks.

The XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_grey_09">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_header_height"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
            android:id="@+id/composeView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Fragment A code:

```kotlin
    override fun initView() {
        initHeader()
        initComposeView()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        binding.composeView.disposeComposition() // Just a workaround.
    }

    private fun initComposeView() {
        Timber.d("==> initComposeView")
        binding.composeView.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                MdcTheme {
                    val state =
                        viewModel.state.collectAsState(initial = AppUnlockIntervalViewModel.ViewState())
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)) {
                        Text(
                            text = getStringByKey(R.string.auth_setting_security_unlock_desc),
                            style = TextStyle(
                                color = colorResource(
                                    id = R.color.light_grey_09
                                ),
                                fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(resId = R.font.inter_regular)),
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                lineHeight = 24.sp
                            ),
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                        )
                        Timber.d("==> initComposeView: Init text desc")
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                        IntervalList(
                            list = state.value.datasource,
                            selectedInterval = state.value.selectedInterval
                        )
                        Timber.d("==> initComposeView: Init list")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun IntervalList(list: List<LockTimeInterval>, selectedInterval: LockTimeInterval) {
        LazyColumn {
            items(count = list.size) { position ->
                val selected = selectedInterval == list[position]
                IntervalListItem(position, list[position], selected)
            }
        }
    }
```

BaseFragment which Fragment A extended from.

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        /**
         * To saving view state we no need to inflate layout every time.
         * Just reuse the view binding if it already created
         */
        if (!::binding.isInitialized) {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, container, false)
        }
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initData()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initView()
        initViewListener()
        initHeaderViewListener()
        initBackgroundListener()
        initObserver()
        enableSavedStateHandles()
    }
```

Comment: You can't "reuse" your `binding` object like that - you'll find tools like LeakCanary correctly signify that as a leak.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, Thanks for pointing this out. I tried to recreate the binding without keeping it. Is that the real issue about ComposeView not disposable?